# Auditing on PDF documents in a library

Tags: pdf, auditing

Had a request to see how often a pdf was being used within a document library so i setup a test library in one of my team sites and was able to enable auditing on the library, after some open attempts on the PDFs i placed in it...i ran the site collection audit report to see the numbers and it generated properly.

WHen i tried to recreate the scenario in another site however, i wasn't able to see pdf files on the report...the auditing would show me .doc files and .xls files but not show me any stats on the .pdf files. Is there something i have to configure in the library so that PDF files are visable on the reports...something that might have been enabled in my test site that wasn't in this other site?

really scratching my head on this one....

Answer (score 1):

I was once involved in the development of a SharePoint Auditing product (now owned by Idera, give it a try http://www.idera.com/productssolutions/sharepoint/spaudit) so I have had quite a lot of exposure to SharePoint's (shaky) auditing facilities.

Having said that, I have never actually encountered your particular situation. Are the PDF files perhaps served up from the local browser cache or is there some kind of (3rd party) HTTP Module involved that bypasses the normal file access facilities for PDF files?

Comment: Not to sure I follow what your speaking about with regards to cache or 3rd party module...I know there is no 3rd party solution involved in what i'm doing it's all out of the box.

Comment: Problem is that one library in a team site will properly audit the pdf open attempts, however another library in a different teamsite will not. They are both in the same web app and site collection.

Comment: Are both libraries using the same content types? Is there no SharePoint solutions (WSPs) installed on this farm whatsoever? Regarding caching, I was talking about your browser cache. Try clearing it (it is a long shot)

Comment: Appreciate the follow up, it appears that they are using the same content type. as far as WSPs, we do have those loaded into the farm...not sure how one of them could be affecting this library...i guess that's something to investigate or consider.

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint 2010 is not setup with PDF files as a document type by default and search will not index them.  It is possible that PDFs are not setup as a document type on the new server.  The Article below may help.

How to install and configure Adobe PDF iFilter 9 for SharePoint 2010
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2293357

Comment: I have the pdf ifilter installed and search does recognize the pdf files. Problem is that one library in a team site will properly audit the pdf open attempts, however another library in a different teamsite will not. They are both in the same web app and site collection.

Comment: Can you search from the top site collection level and find the PDF files that are stored in the team site that is not working?